# Possible Bug with MultinomialDistribution

Tags: random-process

I think there is a bug in MultinomialDistribution[]. I want to generate N random variables with densities  vec{p}={p1,p2,p3,...}

Of course I check that Total[vec{p}]=1 (they are densities so they sup up to 1).

Then I run RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[N, {p1,p2,p3,..}]]

It gives me the error:
BinomialDistribution::probprm: Parameter 1.000000000000032` at position 2 in BinomialDistribution[147914,1.] is expected to be between 0 and 1 inclusive.

RandomVariate::distv: The result returned by Random`DistributionVector for the distribution MultinomialDistribution[7065081,{0.0000273949,0.00181668,0.0000287371,0.0000829715,4.14103*10^-6,<<23>>,0.000244175,0.000468644,0.000268529,7.85256*10^-6,<<5223>>}] was {{212,12896,168,561,26,1181,1647,3246,1901,43,<<5223>>}}, which is not a vector of complex numbers of length 1.

It looks likes the densities do not sum up to 1, but I assure that they do (tested with Total).
Both N and the number of components of vec{p} are large, so that may be the reason, it is like Binomial is approximating badly something. Here is the N and the vec{p}. Here you can find the notebook with an example of N and vec{p}:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10akc6La0prsiqx5Zgj221MLrJD5nkCCn?usp=share_link

Comment: Can you concretize your question? `RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[100, {1/2, 1/6, 1/3}], 50]` works well for me.

Comment: Almost `1` is not `1`. Don't use machine precision. `pvec = Rationalize[pvec, 0]; pvec = pvec/Total[pvec]; RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[n1, pvec]]` It will; however, be much slower.

Comment: @user64494 The question is to understand why the case of the notebook I have provided gives error.

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks. I will test Rationalize.